# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'waitid'

Tags: python, python-3.x, sas, anaconda

when i am using `saspy.SASsession()` getting below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/saspy/sasiostdio.py", line 209, in del
self._endsas()
File "opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/saspy/sasiostdio.py", line 376, in _endsas
self._getlog(wait=1)
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/saspy/sasiostdio.py", line 402, in _getlog
rc = os.waitid(os.P_PID, self.pid, os.WEXITED | os.WNOHANG)
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'waitid'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'waitid'
```

Desktop information:

- OS: macos MOJAVE[Linux]
- SAS Version: 9.4M4
- Python Version: Python 3.7.4 [Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)]

Comment: `os.waitid()` should be available on Unix-like systems, including macOS... If you open up your Anaconda Python interpreter and do `import os; os.waitid`, do you get the same attribute error?

Comment: >>> import os 
>>> os.waitid
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'waitid'

Comment: are you sure you executing the right python installment? Type "which python" on terminal and see what you will get

Comment: /Users/saumya.rb/opt/anaconda3/bin/python

Comment: Other attributes are avialble.

Comment: >>> os.waitpid
<built-in function waitpid>

Comment: This does seem like there's something wrong with your Python installation. `os.waitid` was added in Python 3.3...

Comment: should i have to reinstall